# java, putting non local files in a zip

Tags: java, file, zip

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];//time to make zip file
    String zipName="name.zip";
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipName));

    for(int i=0; i<copy.length; i++){//put all pdfs in the zip
        FileInputStream zipFile = new FileInputStream(copy[i]);
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(copy[i]));
        int len;
        while((len=zipFile.read(buf))>0){
            out.write(buf, 0, len);             
        }
        out.closeEntry();
        zipFile.close();
    }   
out.close();
```

copy is an array of strings which contain the file path for each file I want (for example C:\files\test.pdf). It compiles and runs fine with no exceptions and creates the zip folder, but nothing is in said zip folder.

Comment: File[] files=myFile.listFiles(); copy[i]=files[i].toString(); in a loop. I printed it out and it's all valid.

Comment: If you had the files in an array of `File`, why did you convert them to an array of `String`?  Opening a `FileInputStream` directly from the `File` object is supported _and_ better object orientation.  Also, if you check the names in a loop, why don't you also check `System.out.println("File (" + files[i].toString() + ") exists()=" + files[i].exists());`  You might be mistranslating along a different path.

Comment: I converted to string because     out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(copy[i]));
 only accepts a string. I have printed the contents of both folders out as well as putting in exist checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it, posting answer if anyone else needs it.

```
out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));
```

files is an array of files (which I used to create copy).

Comment: Congrats for figuring that out.  The documentation mentions nothing about not using a path (although it makes sense if you think about what an entry in the zip is).  You should accept your answer, BTW

Comment: You can't accept your own answers for 1 day. Thank you kindly.